# Native messaging of Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am running an example application that uses native messaging on OS X.

After downloading [an example of chrome](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging), I registered an extension and located a native messaging host file at /Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/com.google.chrome.example.echo.json.

According to [the guide](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging-host), Chrome starts a native messaging host in a separate process. 
But I cannot look for that process.

Is there a way for chrome to run host process? 
What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

The sample app provided by Chrome is a packaged app. Once you install it you have to launch it from your browser. And then do ps ax and look for the sample python-script process.

Answer (score 0):

To run the app, start chrome and go to the following URL: 
chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/main.html

If you've done everything right, it should start the python script and you should see a window.

if its not working, have a look at chrome's console. you could also enable additional chrome logs - see here: http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging